# How to compare importance of qualitative AND quantitative factors in a mixed linear model?

Tags: r, variables, statistics, linear-regression, mixed-models

I am trying to explain the effects of different variables (qualitative and quantitative) on a quantitative variable. The aim is to see if we can rise its value by acting on the other variables.

For that, I analysed a big dataset (more than 10 000 lines) with a mixed linear model. Prior to constructing the model, I standardized all the quantitative factors.

I would like to compare the importance of the factors' effects on the covariable. The aim is to determine which one is more efficient to use in order to increase the variable of interest's value.

As a result, I need to compare quantitative factors with qualitative factors.

I tried to do that by comparing the "standardized" estimates from my regression between them (for the fixed effects only). I divided these estimates by the standard deviation of the covariable. I supposed this allows me to compare whether if the variations of the covariable due to each factor is important or not, respectively the the overall variation of my covariable.

We can summarize it in this graph :

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMhdj.png)

I think this approach is suited for quantitative variables. I can say for example that increasing the value of the quantitative variable n°1 by one standard deviation decreases the covariable by 40% of its standard deviation, but if we do the same on quantitative variable n°2, it only increases the covariable by 10%. I conclude that quantitative variable n°1 has more effect on the covariable than quantitative variable n°2.

I am not so sure about the qualitative variables.

I figured I could approximate the importance of these qualitative variables by the average effect of all the factor levels. Is it appropriate ?

And I don't know at all how to compare these effects to those of the quantitative variables. Do I need a new method ?

**Edit** : after the comment of Shawn Hemelstrand, I will give you an example. So if you take the mtcars database from the explore package:

[image: mtcars variables]

And you run a mixed model on it (even if it seems unecessary to add a random variable) :

```
library(explore)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

dat= mtcars %>% 
    # Put factors where they should be
    mutate(across(vs, am, gear, carb), ~as.factor(.x)) %>% 
    # Standardize quantitative variables
    mutate((across(where(is.numeric),~scale(.x)))

regession=lme4::lmer(mpg~., data=dat)
```

Then, the aim would be to determine which factor(s) have the most effect on the mpg value, because you want to find ways to augment it. The question would be : do the other variables have effects on the mpg **that matter** relatively to the overall mpg variation, and relatively to the effects of the other variables.

For that, you have to compare quantitative variables with qualitative variable.

PS : I have some factors in my dataset that have more than 80 levels, so comparing each level one by one isn't an option

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Greetings to you too ! I don't think this problem is related specifically to my data, but i guess I could do that in my post to make my problem clearer

Comment: This seems like more of a statistics theory question than a programming question. I think it would be a better fit at stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Related reading: [Scaling regression inputs by dividing by two standard deviations - Gelman](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/standardizing7.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer I was looking for !